# how to make a stack occupy all screen in react navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes, navigation, react-navigation

I have a Drawer navigation as the root navigator, and inside it i have a Stack, but when i open the Stack screen, both titles show.

[image]

Code:

```
export default function Drawer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        {user ? (
          <>
            <Drawer.Screen
              name="home"
              options={{
                title: "Home",
              }}
              component={HomeStack}
            />
          </>
        ) : null}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="list"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="list" component={MyList} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="details"
        component={Details}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTitle: "Back",
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I tried to remove the Drawer title by changing the property headerShown to false when i in that screen, but then it causes a glitchy effect.

I wanna know if theres a way to make my stack screen occopy all the screen height, or if theres a way to simple open it in another window.

Comment: is it possible to rearrange the nesting of navigator so that stack is the main navigator and drawer is nested screen inside it. If yes that reduce a lot of complexities